# Puppet: Mixing registry keys and Variables

Tags: syntax, registry, puppet

I am trying to create a module to configure my systems to point at a certain server. I need to change the registry key of the hostname of the server i require.

The way i have done this is, i have a 'params.pp' which is configured with the command i'd like to run. I also have a hiera value specifying the hostname. The idea is if the hostname ever changes, i just change the hiera value and the module does not need to change.

I am getting a syntax error for the reg.exe command (i'm using puppet exec). the issue is the following code;

```
    $server_add = "reg.exe add HKLM\\SOFTWARE\\path\\to\\registry /f /v KeyName /t REG_SZ /d ${server}"
    $server_query = "reg.exe query HKLM\\SOFTWARE\\path\\to\\registry /v KeyName | findstr.exe ${server}"
```

It wants the double quotes around the registry key path. The issue then is my puppet code cannot access find my variable '${server}'.

I've tried many combination with quotes and double quotes and seem to have no luck.

Any help would be great.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

For the double qoutes around the registry key, please use **\"** in your string:

```
$server_add = "reg.exe add \"HKLM\\SOFTWARE\\path\\to\\registry\" /f /v KeyName /t REG_SZ /d ${server}"
```

It will give you:

```
reg.exe add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\path\to\registry" /f /v KeyName /t REG_SZ /d
```